# Why does this css not display my background?

Tags: html, css

Why does this code have no effect on the HTML?

```css
.main {
      height: 100%;
     }
.main::before {
      content:"";
      display: block;
      background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff) no-repeat 30% 0;
     }
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: What HTML? I see none.

Comment: Depends on the html and where the image is located. Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: the image is being applied via css

Answer (score 2):

`main::before` has no content and no CSS that would give it a non-zero height. It, therefore, provides no pixels on which the background could be painted.

Comment: the image is being displayed via css, it not in the html

Comment: @loveerfdjf — That statement doesn't, in any way, invalidate anything I said in this answer. (Unless you mean that there is no HTML, in which case you would have the additional problem that the selector `main::before` doesn't match anything).